# How to properly use the hook_insert in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, hook, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I created a custom module for Drupal 8. I made a hook that is to detect whenever a new node is created, then send a notification to a subscriber. The code I have is this:

```
<?php 

/**
* @file
* Contains onesignal_api.module.
* 
*/

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

/***
* Hook into OneSignal API to send push notifications once a new node is created
*/

function onesignal_api_insert(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
if($node->isNew()) {
    function sendMessage() {
      $content      = array(
          "en" => 'New Node Created'
      );
      $hashes_array = array();
      array_push($hashes_array, array(
          "id" => "like-button",
          "text" => "Like",
          "icon" => "http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png",
          "url" => "http://push-test/"
      ));
      array_push($hashes_array, array(
          "id" => "like-button-2",
          "text" => "Like2",
          "icon" => "http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png",
          "url" => "http://push-test/"
      ));
      $fields = array(
          'app_id' => "XXXXXXXXX",
          'include_player_ids' => array("XXXXXX","XXXXX","XXXXXX"),
          'data' => array(
              "foo" => "bar"
          ),
          'contents' => $content,
          'web_buttons' => $hashes_array
      );

      $fields = json_encode($fields);
      print("\nJSON sent:\n");
      print($fields);

      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXX'
      ));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

      return $response;
  }

  $response = sendMessage();
  $return["allresponses"] = $response;
  $return = json_encode($return);

  $data = json_decode($response, true);
  print_r($data);
  $id = $data['id'];
  print_r($id);

  print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
  print($return);
  print("\n");

 }//if Node is new
}//func hook signal
```

Is there something that I need to change to get this to work? all of the code inside of the if statement works outside of the if statement.

Comment: [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7.x) is called AFTER the entity has been saved to the databse, that is why your `isNew()` check fails. On the other hand, you do not need to check that condition in `hook_node_insert' anyways because that hook only executes AFTER THE FIRST TIME an entity is saved to the database. So you can be sure this is a newly created node everytime in `hook_node_insert.'

Comment: Ahhh ok. Is there one upon creation of a node? @coderodour

Comment: that would be [`hook_node_submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7.x), which is ideal place to have all the values available for manipulation, right BEFORE saving the node in the database.

Comment: It looks like that has been deprecated for drupal 8 @coderodour

Comment: [hook_entity_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) is an alternative, see if it fits your needs.

Comment: That didn't do it. I'm trying hook_entity_create now @coderodour

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to implement **hook_node_presave**.

It acts on a node being created or updated *before* it is saved to the database :

```
function onesignal_api_node_presave(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
  if ($node->isNew()) {
    // $node is about to be created...
  }
}
```

*@see [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.6.x)*

Comment: Thanks. For some reason when put some test code such as `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('it works');</script>";` it doesn't work

Comment: @MikeL5799 PHP's output is buffered. Your `echo` actually works here, you won't see it in the output because at some point - after the `echo` - in the script handling the request, the buffer is reset (saying "ok let me discard what have been printed so far and start a fresh and brand new blank page from scratch yeeeeh !!)". So the output you get is the HTML that is built _after_ some operations are effective. This also happens because of redirections. @see [Output Control Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Comment: @MikeL5799 Use the [Logging API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/logging-api/overview) instead. And accept the answer if you think it is ok !

Answer (score 0):

Please look below code and add your code as per your requirements.

```
function onesignal_api_entity_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

  if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'node') {
    switch ($entity->bundle()) {

       case 'content-type-name':    // if multiple entities 
    }
  }     
}
```